# Stochastic gradient descent convergence for non-convex smooth functions

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, nonlinear-optimization

I'm looking for a proof of convergence of stochastic gradient descent applied to a non-convex smooth function. I'm generally interested in just asymptotic convergence, preferably to a critical point, but not necessary to a (local) minimizer.

I have found many relevant results but they all have some additional assumptions such as convexity.

Given that I also don't care much about speed of convergence how can I obtain the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a more recent literature on convergence of a randomized SGD for non-convex functions: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5549v1.pdf

Comment: +1 that's a nice find

Answer (score 3):

Check out Chapter 4 of: Harold Kushner and Dean Clark (1978). **Stochastic Approximation Methods for Constrained and Unconstrained Problems.** Springer-Verlag.  This work proves asymptotic convergence to a stationary point in the non convex case.  See Section 4.1 for their precise assumptions.